# max file descriptors [4096] for elasticsearch process is too low, increase to at least [65536]

Tags: elasticsearch, docker

Using Ubuntu 16.10
Docker 1.12.3
Docker Composer 1.8
Elastic latest tag of official elastic docker image

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
    elastic:
        image: elasticsearch
        environment:
            - ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx2g -Xms2g
```

getting on logs

elastic_1 | ERROR: bootstrap checks failed
elastic_1 | max file descriptors [4096] for elasticsearch process is too low, increase to at least [65536]
elastic_1 | [2016-11-18T17:48:17,058][INFO ][o.e.n.Node ] [HK_OIan] stopping ...

Any idea, thanks

Comment: Google knows https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/file-descriptors.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After reading resources from elasticsearch official doc i manage to start the container updating my docker-compose.yml file by

```
version: '2'
services:
  elastic:
      image: elasticsearch
      environment:
          - ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx2g -Xms2g
      ulimits:
          nofile:
              soft: 65536
              hard: 65536
```

adding the ulimit section

Answer (score 4):

Those who are using a direct `docker run` command instead of docker-compose can set ulimit like below.

```
docker run --ulimit nofile=65536:65536 -p 9200:9200 --name elastic-search docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.4.2
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it helps me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

check for the actual limit when the process is running (albeit short) with:

```
cat /proc/<pid>/limits
```

You will find lines similar to this:

```
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units     
Max cpu time              unlimited            unlimited            seconds   
Max file size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
Max data size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
Max stack size            8388608              unlimited            bytes     
Max core file size        0                    unlimited            bytes 
<truncated>
```

Then depend on the runner or container (in my case it was supervisord's minfds value), you can lift the actual limitation configuration.