# How can I set `max_map_count` and `ulimit` for Elasticsearch node when running in Kubernete in EKS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kubernetes

I am deploying Elasticsearch 7.10.1 to AWS EKS Fargate but I got below error when running them:

```
ERROR: [2] bootstrap checks failed
[1]: max number of threads [1024] for user [elasticsearch] is too low, increase to at least [4096]
[2]: max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]
```

I found solutions for them is [max file descriptors [4096] for elasticsearch process is too low, increase to at least [65536]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40683285/max-file-descriptors-4096-for-elasticsearch-process-is-too-low-increase-to-at) and [Elasticsearch: Max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51445846/elasticsearch-max-virtual-memory-areas-vm-max-map-count-65530-is-too-low-inc).

But both requires a change on the host machine. I am using EKS Fargate which means I don't have access to the Kubernete cluster host machine. What else should I do to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to set these via privileged init containers within your Elasticsearch pod/deployment/statefulset, for example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch-node
spec:
  initContainers:
    - name: increase-vm-max-map
      image: busybox
      command: ["sysctl", "-w", "vm.max_map_count=262144"]
      securityContext:
        privileged: true
    - name: increase-fd-ulimit
      image: busybox
      command: ["sh", "-c", "ulimit -n 65536"]
      securityContext:
        privileged: true
  containers:
    - name: elasticsearch-node
      ...
```

You could also do this through Daemonsets, although Daemonsets aren't very well suited to one-time tasks (but it's possible to hack around this).
But the init container approach will guarantee that your expected settings are in effect precisely before an Elasticsearch container is launched.

Comment: Tried this approach but doesn't work for fargate. I got this error when describe the pod: `Pod not supported on Fargate: invalid SecurityContext fields: Privileged,Privileged`